# FreeTextBox (FTB) is not working in FF 17

Tags: firefox, freetextbox

FreeTextBox (http://www.freetextbox.com/demos/) does not work in Firefox 17. What has changed? 
FTB works correctly in previous Firefox versions and in all versions of other browsers.
(FreeTextBox develop has been terminated: "Please note that FreeTextBox has been discontinued. You may still purchase the software, but it is considered unsupported.")
Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: There may be a fix for this, but Stack Overflow isn't really the place for bug fixes. Either way, it's probably going to be wiser to change to a product that is supported - the next breaking change in some browser will come eventually

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. Problem was, the FTB anticipates value in the userAgent string part "Gecko/date", which then parses, creates a date object and compares if the returned date is greater than that which is permitted. However, because the value that Firefox now 17 uses, is changed to "Gecko/17.0", an exception occurs and the variable isMozillaEditor is not assigned value to true (this is done in the file BrowserInfo.cs). Therefore, the FTB does not start.